# FontAwesome Icon Buttons are not the same size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome

I am using fontawesome with my buttons but they are not the same size as shown in the pictures. I have tried `fa-fw` options but that makes things even worse. Any ideas what I can try ?

[image]

[image]

```
<td>
    <a href="@Url.Action("MemberEmployees", "Employees", new { @item.MemberId })"><span title="Personel" class="btn btn-default btn-sm  fa fa-user" /></a>
    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Documents",new { @item.MemberId })"><span title="Belgeler" class="btn btn-default btn-sm   glyphicon fa fa-inbox" /></a>
    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Logs",new { @item.MemberId })"><span title="Kayıtlar" class="btn btn-default btn-sm glyphicon fa  fa-folder" /></a>
    <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Members", new { @item.MemberId })"><span title="Araçlar" class="btn btn-default btn-sm   fa fa-truck" /></a>
    <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Members", new { @item.MemberId })"><span title="Güncelle" class="btn btn-default btn-sm  fa fa-pencil" /></a>
    <a class="modal-link" href="@Url.Action("Delete", "Members",new { @item.MemberId })"><span title="Sil" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm  fa fa-trash" /></a>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the `glyphicon` classes in your HTML. http://jsfiddle.net/q6bpdsmt/1/

Fixed HTML:

```
<td>
    <a href="@Url.Action("MemberEmployees", "Employees", new { @item.MemberId })"><span title="Personel" class="btn btn-default btn-sm fa fa-user" /></a>
    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Documents",new { @item.MemberId })"><span title="Belgeler" class="btn btn-default btn-sm fa fa-inbox" /></a>
    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Logs",new { @item.MemberId })"><span title="Kayıtlar" class="btn btn-default btn-sm fa fa-folder" /></a>
    <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Members", new { @item.MemberId })"><span title="Araçlar" class="btn btn-default btn-sm fa fa-truck" /></a>
    <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Members", new { @item.MemberId })"><span title="Güncelle" class="btn btn-default btn-sm fa fa-pencil" /></a>
    <a class="modal-link" href="@Url.Action("Delete", "Members",new { @item.MemberId })"><span title="Sil" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm fa fa-trash" /></a>
</td>
```

Comment: This may sound silly but although this works I am failing to see what exactly you have changed

Comment: @Cemre I removed the 'glyphicon' class from the second and third span.

Answer (score 2):

http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/

here's the link..To increase icon sizes relative to their container, use the fa-lg (33% increase), fa-2x, fa-3x, fa-4x, or fa-5x classes.
hope this works..